# Error in reading image from NetworkStream

Tags: c#

I have recieved an image with some text while reading from a `NetworkStream`. The stream includes something like this:

```
HTTP/1.0 200 OK
Expires: -1
Cache-Control: no-cache
Content-length: 29160
Content-type: image/jpeg
```

...followed by the image.

How can I read just the image from the `NetworkStream`?

Answer (score 2):

You would have to parse the HTTP header first, to know where to stop discarding data. Alternatively, save the whole thing and then examine it afterwards, which may be simpler. Basically you'd be looking for two ASCII carriage-return/line-feed ("\r\n") pairs in a row.

However, there's a much better alternative: *use an HTTP library*. Parsing this yourself is like using text manipulation to handle XML; you're better off working at a higher level of abstraction with code which has been well tested for that abstraction.

Comment: I have parsed Http Header already, we get bytes only between FFD8 and FFD9. Actually problem is cropped image.